# Why list is twice of its size?

Tags: python, python-2.7

With given list:

```
x = [x for x in range(10)]
```

Printing out indexes and values:

```
for i in range(-10, len(x)):
    print i, ": ", x[i]
```

The output is:

```
-10 :  0
-9 :  1
-8 :  2
-7 :  3
-6 :  4
-5 :  5
-4 :  6
-3 :  7
-2 :  8
-1 :  9
0 :  0
1 :  1
2 :  2
3 :  3
4 :  4
5 :  5
6 :  6
7 :  7
8 :  8
9 :  9
```

but

```
print x
```

returns:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Why is the actual list twice as long as the initialized list?

Comment: A simple `print(len(x))` would tell alleviate any doubts about the length

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using *negative indexes*. Those work too; in Python an index < 0 indexes from the end. So there are *two different ways* of indexing elements, counting from the start and from the end.

For example, the index `2` and `-8` both refer to the 3rd element in `x`, so both indexes give you the value `2`.

As such, the list is not twice as long, you are just printing the values twice; once for the negative index, and once again for the positive.

See note #3 under the [sequence types operations table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

> 3. If *i* or *j* is negative, the index is relative to the end of the string: `len(s) + i` or `len(s) + j` is substituted. But note that `-0` is still `0`.

or from the [*Introduction* section of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

> Indices may also be negative numbers, to start counting from the right:
>
> ```
> >>> word[-1]  # last character
> 'n'
> >>> word[-2]  # second-last character
> 'o'
> ```

Answer (score 6):

**Python support negative indexes as well as  positive indexes to access an element of a list.**

In negative indexes, an element is accessed from the end of the list counting backwards.

So,
Element at index `-1` is basically the last element of the list i.e. element at index `9`.
Element at index `-2` is the second last element i.e element at index `8`.
..
..
Element at index `-10` is the first element i.e element at index `0`.

**Your list size is not double. You are just printing out the same element twice when infact they are the same object, you are just using 2 different ways to access the same object.**

You can check that they are the same using the `is` operator.

```
>>> x[0] is x[-10] # Both point to the same object
True

>>> x[1] is x[-9] # Both point to the same object
True
...
...
>>> x[9] is x[-1] # Both point to the same object
True
```

Comment: Better to use `==` than `is` for Python strings

Comment: `==` checks for equality but `is` will infact check for the object identity.

Comment: So `a is b` will be `True` only if `a` and `b` are the same object.

Comment: @ytpillai, can you elaborate? Two equal `str`s (or `int`s for that matter) created separately by literals are identical: e.g. this snippet `x = 'a'; y = 'a'; x is y` returns `True`.

Comment: Yes, but if you have two different objects of the same value, this will not work. If `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = a`, then `b is a[:]` is false but `b == a[:]` is true. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: OK, but my point (and your initial remark) concerns `int`s and `str`s specifically. From my example it looks like that `str`s with the same values are always identical. You can even try: `x = 'abc'; y = x[:]; x is y` (it returns `True`). So again: why is it better to use `==` than `is` for `str`s?

Comment: Ah, I read up the question pointed by you and it indeed seems that it is better to use `==` — for both `int`s and `str`s: "In your case, the second test only works because Python caches small integer objects, which is an implementation detail. For larger integers, this does not work". So I stand corrected. :) And thanks for the interesting link!

Comment: `lst = [1, 1, 1]; lst[0] is lst[1] -> True; lst[1] is lst[2] -> True`. Both indices mean the same thing to Python **vs** two indices point to the same object are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

An array of 10 elements in python,

```
x of index     0   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
= x of index  -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
```

see [python 2.7 documentation tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

In your code:

```
for i in range(-10, len(x)):
    print i, ": ", x[i]
```

would have i run from -10 to len(x)-1, which in detail = -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, ..., 9.

That's 20 iterations in total, which explains why you get twice as len(x).

I guess what you want is:

```
for i in range(-len(x), 0):
    print i, ": ", x[i]
```

This would give normal size = len(x).